# Having a Class name "System"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am creating an MVC project with .NET. A database already exist and I'm using the Entity Framework to access the database.

One of the tables in the database is called "System". EF therefore creates a class by that name. This obviously a conflict with the "System" namespace.

Renaming the table is not practical at this point. Is there another way I can use EF for my project?

Thanks

Comment: Renaming the table in the database might not be appropriate, but you *can* rename the generated model. If that's acceptable to you, try it via the model browser.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a problem, you simply need to reference the class through its namespace.

e.g.:

If your generated entity class is under the namespace AppName.EntityModel, the following would work

```
global::AppName.EntityModel.System
AppName.EntityModel.System
EntityModel.System // if already under the AppName namespace
```